# Java keytool won't parse Extensions of my CA certificate

Tags: certificate, keytool, self-signed

I'm currently creating an Android app, which is supposed to send a POST request to a server. Unfortunately, the server is using self-signed certificate. So I have to create a PKCS12 keystore, which will include the CA Certificate, and make my App use that keystore.

To create such a keystore, I'm currently using the command below:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias my-alias -file cacert.pem
-keystore mykeystorefile -storetype PKCS12
```

Unfortunately the keystore doesn't work. (Request fails on SSL handshake.)

When I inspected the keystore using this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mykeystorefile
```

I noticed a strange line at the very end of this list.

```
#8: ObjectId: 2.5.29.18 Criticality=false
Unparseable IssuerAlternativeName extension due to
java.io.IOException: No data available in passed DER encoded value.

0000: 30 00                                              0.



*******************************************
*******************************************
```

Keytool failed to parse an extension, which is part of the CA certificate.

I tried the same for LetsEncrypt's CA certificates and it worked just fine.

I'd be glad for any pointers on how to approach and solve this problem.

Thanks.

**Edit:** Keytool I'm currently using is part of java-8-openjdk.

**Edit2:** So after inspecting the ca certificate, Issuer Alternative Name extension doesn't have any value. Wondering if there is a way how to skip that extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to skip anything that's on a certificate.

If the Issuer Alternative Name is blank, whoever generated that certificate has generated it wrong. If it is a self-signed certificate, the Issuer Alternative Name and the Subject Alternative Name are the same value. If it is signed by any CA, the CA's Subject Alternative Name is put in the end user's Issuer Alternative Name.

You might need to ask them for the right CA certificate.